# Getting the battery or CPU temperature on android in JS

Tags: javascript, android

How do I get access to the temperature of the battery ir CPU in android?

Comment: Are you talking about mobile web JavaScript. Or React Native?

Comment: @XuezhengMa mobile web JavaScript